# Mysterious t before every item of listofexercises

Tags: exercises

I use the `exercises` package to create exercises inside a script file but in my `\listofexercises` there is a t at the beginning of every entry, which I couldn't find any explanation for. How do I fix this?
[image]

I tried differnt languages via babel, but the problem remains the same.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofexercises
\section{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{framed}
\begin{Exercise}[
title={Integration 1},
difficulty=0,
origin=myself, label=aufg1]
Integrieren Sie folgende Funktion:
\[\left(\sin (x)+\cos(x)\right)^{e^{-x}}\]
\end{Exercise}
\end{framed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `exercise` has two `\expandafter` commands in the wrong place; they're actually wrong and *must* be removed.

There's a telltale warning you get:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/jkp/m/i' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/jkp/m/n' instead on input line 1.
```

which stems from the line in the `loe` file

```
\contentsline {exercise}{{\"U}bung\ 1\ {\relax \fontshape it\selectfont Integration 1}\hspace {.66em}}{1}{}%
```

Obviously `\fontshape it` is wrong and is produced by the wrong `\expandafter` we'll remove.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{exercise}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% remove the faulty \expandafter
\patchcmd{\@@@ExeEnv}
  {\theExercise\ \expandafter}
  {\theExercise\ }
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@@@ExeCmd}
  {\theExercise\ \expandafter}
  {\theExercise\ }
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofexercises
\section{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{framed}
\begin{Exercise}[
title={Integration 1},
difficulty=0,
origin=myself, label=aufg1]
Integrieren Sie folgende Funktion:
\[\left(\sin (x)+\cos(x)\right)^{e^{-x}}\]
\end{Exercise}
\end{framed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` that's really necessary for typesetting in German.

Now the `loe` file will have the right incantation:

```
\contentsline {exercise}{{\"U}bung\ 1\ {\itshape Integration 1}\hspace {.66em}}{1}{}%
```

[image]

If you also want to remove `\itshape`, do a second series of patches.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{exercise}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% remove the faulty \expandafter
\patchcmd{\@@@ExeEnv}
  {\theExercise\ \expandafter}
  {\theExercise\ }
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@@@ExeCmd}
  {\theExercise\ \expandafter}
  {\theExercise\ }
  {}{}
% remove \itshape
\patchcmd{\@@@ExeEnv}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@@@ExeCmd}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofexercises
\section{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{framed}
\begin{Exercise}[
title={Integration 1},
difficulty=0,
origin=myself, label=aufg1]
Integrieren Sie folgende Funktion:
\[\left(\sin (x)+\cos(x)\right)^{e^{-x}}\]
\end{Exercise}
\end{framed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SimonDispa There are two commands that have the wrong `\expandafter`. Now I realize I didn't change the second one! Oops!

Comment: Is there a way to remove the \itshape as well?

Comment: @pmaen I added it.